# Merge dataframes and extract only the rows of the dataframe that does not exist in the other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes and create a new dataframe containing only the rows from the first dataframe that does not exist in the second one. For example:

The dataframes that I have as input:

[image]

The dataframe that I want to have as output:

[image]

Do you know if there is a way to do that? If you could help me, I would be more than thankful!! Thanks, Eleni

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating some data, we have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=5)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=rng.integers(0, 5, size=(5, 2)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=rng.integers(0, 5, size=(5, 2)))
```

```
# df1
   a  b
0  3  4
1  0  4
2  2  2
3  3  1
4  4  0

# df2
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  0  0
3  0  0
4  0  4
```

We can use `pandas.merge` to combine equal rows. And we can use its `indicator=True` feature to mark those rows that are only from the left (and right, when applicable). Since we only need those that are unique to left, we can merge using `how="left"` to be more efficient.

```
dfm = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=list(df1.columns), how="left", indicator=True)
```

```
# dfm

    a   b   _merge
0   3   4   left_only
1   0   4   both
2   2   2   both
3   3   1   left_only
4   4   0   left_only
```

Great, so then the final result is using the merge
but only keeping those that have an indicator of `left_only`:

```
(dfm.loc[dfm._merge == 'left_only']
    .drop(columns=['_merge']))
```

```
    a   b
0   3   4
3   3   1
4   4   0
```

---

*If* you'd want to deduplicate by a subset of the columns, that should be possible. In that case I would do the merge it like this, repeating the subset so that we don't get other columns in duplicate versions from the left and right side.

`pd.merge(df1, df2[subset], on=subset, how="left", indicator=True)`